# UITextField placeholder and text not aligned in iOS9

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uistoryboard

I have a simple UITextField (center aligned) I placed using storyboards, with a standard font. For some reason as soon as I start typing the text renders in a different spot from the placeholder text.

This is on iOS9 running on Yosemite (XCode V7.0)

[image: placeholder image]
[image: text image]

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: This is expected behaviour, the text starts appearing where it is aligned

Comment: @Mr.T right, but shouldn't the placeholder and normal text be shown in the same spot? This was never an issue before.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some issue with storyboards occurred. I redid this view, and now it works fine. Strange.